# User's home folder path displaying problem

Tags: macos, finder, path

Let's say the name of my current account is `johndoe`.

Open Finder Preferences, and set "New Finder window show" to `johndoe`, and add it to sidebar. Then each time opening up Finder after a reboot or log out/in, it will display the full path on the Finder window (screenshot below).

```
Macintosh HD > Users > johndoe
```

Rather than display `johndoe` as the relevant root, the behavior on OS X 10.7 and before (screenshot below).

```
johndoe
```

However, close any Finder window and reopen, problem disappears. But after reboot and log out/in problem repeats.

Affecting systems: OS X 10.8 and 10.9, unknown on 10.10

Example (system root):

[image]

Example (relevant root):

[image]

Comment: I guess, that it's just Finder trying to be intelligent, and wanting to fill up all the space in the windows and showing the whole path first time you open it.

Comment: First of all, out of curiosity: what makes showing the folder hierarchy "bad" for you? And second: does this happen for *all windows* (including new ones) after you reboot or only for those that are automatically re-opened from the last session?

Comment: @MarekBettman I like your theory :P

Comment: @Asmus You're right, I shouldn't say bad there, just removed the word, was just trying to make it clear. Only the first opening Finder window after reboot or log out/in shows the system root, any new window shows the relevant root. There is no auto reopen/session, I don't use the feature of "reopen windows automatically".

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

1. Delete the sidebar shortcut of johndoe
2. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>
3. Enter `/Users/johndoe` into the textbox
4. Press Go
5. Now drag the home icon at the top of the fider window to the sidebar

Or try right clicking on the home folder and click open in new window

Comment: Unfortunately, that makes no difference, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Window display information is stored in the `.DS_Store` files (since it starts with a dot, you can't see it by default in the finder). These files are created everytime you see or change something in the finder. They are stored in each folder to describe the view mode, icon locations, etc. I've had problems with them in the past and sometimes it can help to delete them and let the system create new ones.

I would first try removing all the `.DS_Store` files in the directories that its displaying. Based on your screenshot it looks like its displaying all the way down to the root of your volume. Navigate there with in Terminal and remove the `.DS_Store` files. Also remove the one in the user's home folder as it could also be contributing to this behavior, since that's where you'd like to display properly

Here's how:
Open Terminal, then close all finder windows.
In terminal do the following:

```
cd /Volumes/<YourDriveName>
sudo rm -f .DS_Store
```

Then do the user folder as well:

```
cd ~
rm -f .DS_Store
```

Now open a new window in the finder and navigate to your johndoe home folder. Make it appear the way you want then close the window and reboot.

If none of that works, try trashing the finder prefs in `/Users/johndoe/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`

Comment: I'm quite familiar with Terminal, and I know what .DS_Store does in general. The issue happens on multiple Macs that I manage, including fresh installed systems. I can confirm that removing both .DS_Store files does not help.